# Provide access to user based on rule in a organisation website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, angularjs

I have a website with user login and dB describing his / her roles . 
All the pages in the website are not accessible to everyone . The accessibility of each page should be based on the user role .
Ie the accessibility a manager of the organisation has will be different from that of a technician and both will be different from the accessibility of a trainee .

How can I implement this in my website easily ?

Comment: Might as well hire somebody to code for you.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0):

You should check Angular Acl (Access Control List)

Documentation:
https://github.com/mikemclin/angular-acl